# Drupal 8 - Generate carousel from custom content type

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, carousel, drupal-8

I begin to work on D8 few days ago. I want to build a website as you can do it with Wordpress + ACF using D8 and its Content type.

Steps are similar : creating a specific page > add custom fields > display them how we want in the page.

I managed to display some content by reaching the value in the big D8 datas :

```
// example for a h1 tag
<h1>{{ node.field_accueil_slide_titre.value }}</h1>
```

Using node or content main Object/array. By the way it's already difficult and quite stupid to have to delve the node/content array to guess the ".value", ".uri" or ".title" that are needed when we want specific things. Is that the good way to do ? I can't find a doc or listing about it.

My point is that I now want to make something as a "foreach loop" on the field that contains images but I can't find a way to reach images in a clean array.
And if I try to display the field to delve my chrome tab crash..

```
{% for images in content.field_accueil_image_slide %}
```

This do not works for example.

Do I have to generate a new block just for the carousel generation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step:
you have to create a new content-type with a field pictures and the setting unlimited (you can upload as many pictures as you want for your carousel).

second step:
create a new template for this content-type. in your template you can loop through the uploaded pictures.

for example: (my field in the contenttype is field_carousell_picture).

i use owl-carousel. i have included the owl-carousel java-script and call it with the style tag.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
        {% for i in 0..content.field_carousell_picture|length %}
         {%if content.field_carousell_picture[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value != "" and content.field_carousell_picture[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value is not empty %}
            <div>
                {{ content.field_carousell_picture[i]}}
            </div>
         {%endif%}
        {%endfor%} 
      </div>
    </div>
```

third step: you can watch your node and see your carousel or include it to  a page.

Comment: Step one : Done, its my custom content-type that it used for my Home Page. Step twp : Done : node--page-accueil.html.twig, I'm calling my fields (h1 example) in it. Step three : What I needed, I'll try your %for loop because mine (paste in my Q) doesn't work..

Comment: Seems to be working :) I was just looking for this : "0..content.field_accueil_image_slide" and "content.field_accueil_image_slide[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value". My chrome crash when I kint() content or content.myfield then I couldn't go deeper and study my array. 
How do you find the good "path" to the variable and the "0..content." thing ? 
+1

Comment: @PaulLeclerc http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html its twig specific. 0..10 means from 0 to 10.